# i need a shortcode function to my php contact form page (its not a wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql

i have created a contact page using php. I am sending email to the contact in database.

The database contain Name and email

when i send the email i include the [name] to my email it have to converted to the name of the email receiver.

Can anyone help me to do it

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a "We do things 4 free." Site. Show us what you have and we might be able to help you.

Comment: its not fair, i just beginner- so i asked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string replace.

```
$new = str_replace('[name]', $row['name'], $emailbody); // search, replace, original
```

-> http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php